# Simulink sim command does not use time data in input timeseries

Tags: unit-testing, time, simulink

I am trying to learn how to make test harnesses in Simulink. To do so, I have made a simple cross product block and attached two vector inputs (u,v) to it.
[image: test_harnness_cross_product]

Inside the cross_product, is this architecture:
[image: cross_product_contents]

To run the test, I have a separate script that calls the sim() command:

```
%% SETUP
clear, clc, close all


%overwrite these params just to be safe that they are correct...
options.LoadExternalInput = 'on';
options.ExternalInput = 'u_in, v_in';
options.StopTime = 'end_time';

% generate vector data
u_in_data = [1 0 0; 0 1 0];
v_in_data = [0 1 0; 0 0 1];

% u_in_data = 10*rand(num_el,3)-5; % 10x3 of -5 to 5
% v_in_data = 10*rand(num_el,3)-5; % 10x3 of -5 to 5

% sim options
sim_dt = 1;
model_name = 'harness_cross_product';
u_size = size(u_in_data);
num_el = u_size(1);
end_time = num_el-sim_dt;
y_out_e = zeros(num_el,3);
test_limit = 1e-9;

% Generate time data
u_in_time = 0:sim_dt:end_time;
v_in_time = u_in_time;

% define input timeseries
u_in = timeseries(u_in_data, u_in_time);
v_in = timeseries(v_in_data, v_in_time);

%% sim
simOut = sim(model_name,options);

%% comparison and scoring
y_out  = simOut.yout{1}.Values.Data;
y_out = y_out(1:num_el,:);

% fetch expected results
for indx=1:num_el
    y_out_e(indx,:) = cross(u_in_data(indx,:),v_in_data(indx,:));
end

% scoring
res_norm = norm(y_out-y_out_e);
if res_norm < test_limit
    test_score = 'passed';
else
    test_score = 'failed!';
end

disp(['Test ' test_score]);
```

When I run the script it does not return [0 0 1; -1 0 0] as it should. Rather, it returns a 51 row by 3 column array of data. I am nearly positive this has something to do with sim() not understanding that I want it to use the discrete times u_in.Time = [0; 1] because it instead generates its own vector of times simOut.tout = [0:0.02:1]; Is there some name value pair I need to include in the options struct that I haven't?

Comment: The time vector specified in the data coming in through an inport has no effect on the simulation time.  It is purely used to interpolate the data at the time steps that the solver decides to take.  By default you should have seen a warning that Simulink was using the Variable Step Discrete solver (irrespective of what solver you originally selected) because you have no states in your model.

Comment: You get a 51 row output because the solver step size is set to auto (by default), which means it takes steps of (Stop Time - Start Time)/50.  You were using the a Stop Time = 1, and Start Time = 0, which means steps sizes of 0.02 for a total of 51 steps.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue. If you have this issue, make sure to check:

ModelConfigurationParameters> SolverOptions> Type [select "Fixed-step" from the drop down menu]

and

ModelConfigurationParameters> SolverOptions> Solver [select "discrete (no continuous states)" from the drop down menu]

Once *both* of these options were selected. My test passed.

Edit: It may also be necessary to set

```
ModelConfigurationParameters> Additional options> Fixed-step size [set equal to 1]
```